# it works in c but not in java?

Tags: java, string

The following code to gets the vowel deleted from array, and the array rearranges itself.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int a = 0,k=0;
  Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("enter string");
  String s= obj.nextLine();
  char c[]=new char[s.length()];
  c = s.toCharArray();
  for(int i =0; i<s.length();i++){
    if(c[i]=='a'|| c[i]=='i'|| c[i]=='o'||c[i]=='u'||c[i]=='e'){
      for(int j=0;j<s.length();j++){
        c[j]=c[j+1];
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: i an getting exception when i run it..

Comment: Could you include the exception in the question?

Comment: Arrayindex outof bound exception

Comment: What happens when j = s.length - 1?

Comment: What is the output of the code? How do you print it?

Comment: c[j]=c[j+1]; is the problem. j+1 will be out of the array c. Change j<s.length() to j<s.length() - 1

Comment: can anybody tell me how could i convert this char array to string..so i could print it straight a way

Comment: It does NOT work in C.  It simply fails to throw an exception.

Comment: @DavidWallace..yes it works in C..i used "int p= sizeof(c)/sizeof(c[0]);

Comment: Copying a piece of undefined memory into an array doesn't constitute "working".  Java is smart enough to stop you from performing such an abomination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `j` for loop, you have this statement:

```
c[j]=c[j+1];
```

The `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` comes when `j` is the last possible index, and you attempt to access the index element one too high.

You can stop when you get to `s.length() - 1`.

Additionally, you are shifting everything down, not just past where you found a vowel.  Start your `j` for loop not at `0`, but at `i`.

```
for(int j=i;j<s.length() - 1;j++){
```

You'll also have to decide what to do with the end of the array, which is not getting overwritten with anything here.

Comment: @rgettman...thanks buddy..could you just help me more by telling me how to print this array without loop..

Comment: Simple.  `System.out.println(c);`.  There's an [overload of `println` that takes a `char[]`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println(char[])).

Comment: @rgettman..if i use it this way..System.out.println("array is"+c);

Comment: it creates a problem why?

Comment: Because now you're attempting to concatenate a `char[]` to a `String`, which doesn't work.  You can always have 2 calls: `System.out.print("array is ");  System.out.println(c);`.

Comment: @rgettman..one more thing..after deletion of last vowel..it fills remaining empty array elements with last value in array. for example: "this is a dog" will be ths s dggggg..like this

Comment: That's true.  That's why I included the last sentence in my answer.

Comment: what you suggest i could do??

Comment: Keep track of the number of vowels you've removed.  Copy the array to a new array of length `c.length - numVowels`.  Also, your `k` and `a` variables aren't used and can be removed, and you don't need to allocate the `c` array; `toCharArray()` creates and returns the array for you (you could just say `char c[] = s.toCharArray();`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change an array by pointing one location to the next: `c[j]=c[j+1];` That line will only replace the character at `c[j]` but it won't remove that position entirely from the array. You'd need to create a new array with the vowels removed.

This also explains the out-of-bounds exception which happens when you're at the end of the array. You're trying to access the element at `j + 1` but that is outside the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int j=0;j<s.length();j++){
  c[j]=c[j+1];
}
```

Your problem is here. `c[j+1]` is referencing a location beyond the end of your array. When you assign `c[j]` a value from that location, you're trying to retrieve a location that does not exist. This causes an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same effect by transforming the string with a RegExp:

`s.replaceAll("[aioue]","");`

Comment: @jjuraszek..can explain more please

Answer (score 0):

This works in C because the size of the string with `strlen` is one less than the actual size including the `\0` at the end. When you copy all the characters down, you are moving the termination character as well.  Java doesn't use termination characters and doesn't have a character which is beyond the end of the String.

In Java it is more natural to write a regular expression like this and work with Strings from the start.

```
System.out.println("enter string");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = scan.nextLine();
String noVowels = line.replaceAll("[AEIOUaeiou]", "");
System.out.println("Without vowels the line is '" + noVowels + "'");
```

Or you can use this regex

```
// (?i) mean case insensitive
String noVowels = line.replaceAll("(?i)[aeiou]", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

you have the length of string is 4 and you put it on c[s.length] mean it start from 0-3 array indexing. in the second loop you swap the c[j+1] int c[j]. it cause array index out of bounds.
try this in the second loop

```
for (int j = 0; j < s.length()-1; j++)
   {    
     System.out.println(c[j+1]);
     c[j] = c[j + 1];
    }
```